# SyntaxError when declaring a class in TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm getting an error when declaring a class:

```
// This is all on my test1.ts file content
class WDesign {
    wModel: string;
    wQuer: string;
}

let logWDesign = (wd : WDesign) => {
    console.log(wd.wModel + " " + wd.wQuer);
}

let wd1 : WDesign;
wd1.wModel = "SDS-9985";
wd1.wQuer = "escarni";

logWDesign(wd1);
```

Then, to show on Node command prompt:

```
>node test1.ts
```

I get the following:

```
[filePath].test1.ts:3
    wModel: string;
          ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:617:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:204:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:625:3
```

Typescript ver 3.1.3
Node ver. 8.12.0
Visual Studio Code 1.28.2

Comment: I think it would be `const wd1 = new WDesign();` . if you are using class then it is preferred to declare typing in `constructor()` otherwise change `class` to `interface`

Comment: You can use [ts-node](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node) to execute typescript files directly

Answer (score 0):

You firstly have to transpile the `.ts` file `.js` by simply running the command

```
tsc
node test1.js
```

This will generate `javascript` corresponding to your `typescript` files. Node cannot directly understand typescript. You have to give it javascript code.

You can use [typescript-node-starter](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Node-Starter#typescript-node-starter) code provided by Typescript [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Node-Starter#typescript-node-starter) to save configuration hustle.

Post comments if further help is required.

Comment: I can transpile the `.ts` file with no problems. But what I´d like is to run the `ts` file on Node prompt

Comment: this isn't possible as node cannot understand typescript. It cant parse the extra syntax of typescript lang.